# Loading an existing database into WWW SQL Designer?

Tags: sql, mysql, diagram

I've used [WWW SQL Designer](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/) several times to design databases for applications. I'm now in charge of working on an application with a lot of tables (100+ mysql tables) and I would love to be able to look at the relations between tables in a manner similar to what WWW SQL Designer provides. It seems that it comes with the provisions to hook up to a database and provide a diagram of its structure, but I've not yet been able to figure out exactly how one would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/database-diagram/

This takes a SQL structure (SQL dump) and shows a diagram :)

Comment: Very cool. Now it just needs to work with a few more sql types and do a better job of arranging the diagram

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it doesn't show relations between tables (i.e. foreign keys).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old stuff, but I found the solution (if people are looking for it) : you have to edit the file *backend/php-mysql/index.php* and fill the connection settings. All you need is then to click on **Import From DB**, and then **Load** with the name of your database.

```
function setup_import() {
    define("SERVER","localhost");
    define("USER","");
    define("PASSWORD","");
    define("DB","information_schema");
}
```

Comment: This was accurate for MySQL, but unfortunately what I needed was SQLite, which is only partially implemented. As of March 2016, it looks like the project is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just export the sql query that builds your existing tables, and run that in WWW SQL Designer? Most database management software has that option...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the interface of the designer, I guess that when you run it on your own PHP/MySQL server, you should be able to import existing database with "Import from DB" button in Save/Load dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VISIO to import the database, it will diagram it for you.

Answer (score 0):

btw, have you tried [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com)? They are web-based and support MySQL fairly well. It eats your sql dump and generates the tables and relationships for you.